# Font-size rendeniza maior no Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-font-size, mobile-safari

Existem CSS ou outras razões pelas quais o Safari / iPhone ignoraria algumas configurações de tamanho de fonte? No meu site particular, o Safari no iPhone produz algum tamanho de fonte: texto de 13 px maior do que o tamanho da fonte: texto de 15 px. Será que talvez não suporta tamanho de fonte em alguns elementos?

Comment: Vc está usando seu font-size só em PX, ou tem font em EM, REM e PX?

Comment: Seria interessante mostrar algum exemplo de código (CSS e HTML) e algum print da página para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Vc usou algum tipo de CSS Reset ou Normalize ?

Comment: Olá, estou usando PX para definir o font-size e não estou uasndo nenhum reset ou normalize. No momento não tenho como mandar print pois não tenho nenhum produto Apple por perto, mas assim que possível mando um print de como fica. :)